# How to navigate to a url with batch file, hidden no browser

Tags: batch-file, curl

I have a script that hits a url every few minutes, and that url downloads and parses company emails and enters them into a database. I tried using a cron job but there was some issue with absolute links related to the inner working of the file, so I gave up and created a script

However, the script opens a browser window, and I'd like to have this happen in the background somehow. The script itself doesn't need to login, upload/download. All of that is managed by the url. I just want to get the url as if it were in the browser address bar without it having the be there

I have tried:

```
 start "" http://example.com
```

Then tied it to a vbs file:

```
Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
WshShell.Run chr(34) & "C:\Users\User\run.bat" & Chr(34), 0
Set WshShell = Nothing
```

But that doesn't work

Comment: Have you considered using a tool like curl or wget?

Comment: If you are using VBScript in the first place, then you don't need to use a batch file at all. Perhaps the Internet Explorer Automation object is what you are looking for. Something like `Set IE = WScript.CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")` , `IE.Visible = False` , `IE.Navigate "http://example.com"`

Comment: Upvote for SomethingDark's comment! curl is great for this purpose.

Comment: When you say "that doesn't work", what do you mean? Could you post your expected output as well as your actual output please?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution:

```
Dim waittime : waittime = 5 * 60 * 1000    

do 

Set IE = WScript.CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
IE.Visible = False
IE.Navigate "https://emortgagecapital.com/mlo/0gmail7.php"

    WScript.Sleep(waittime)

loop
```

Runs every 5 min

Credit to @sst